# Cannot uninstall MySQL Connector/Net 6.3 or higher

Tags: .net, windows, uninstallation, mysql-connector

I cannot install MySQL Connector/Net due MS Web Platform because of that error.

> MSI (s) (E4:D8) [12:15:40:237]: Doing action: LaunchConditions Action
>   ended 12:15:40: SetHLMPath. Return value 1. Action start 12:15:40:
>   LaunchConditions. MSI (s) (E4:D8) [12:15:40:238]: Product: MySQL
>   Connector Net 6.5.4 -- A previous version of Connector/Net 6.3 or
>   higher is already installed.  Please uninstall that version first.
>
> Action ended 12:15:40: LaunchConditions. Return value 3. Action ended
>   12:15:40: INSTALL. Return value 3. MSI (s) (E4:D8) [12:15:40:239]:
>   Note: 1: 1708  MSI (s) (E4:D8) [12:15:40:239]: Product: MySQL
>   Connector Net 6.5.4 -- Installation failed.
>
> MSI (s) (E4:D8) [12:15:40:239]: Windows Installer installed the
>   product. Product Name: MySQL Connector Net 6.5.4. Product Version:
>   6.5.4. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Oracle. Installation success or error status: 1603.

I don't have connector installed under `Program Files/MySQL` folder as well as I cannot find any key in `windows registry` with `Connector/Net`

Any clue how I can fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just found 100% working solution and could install MySQL Connector/Net via Web Platform.

What you have to do is just open Windows registry and look up for keys, values, data using 
`MySQL Connector Net` keyword.

Delete all things you will find. That is it!

Answer (score 17):

I've had to battle this for quite a few hours!  I also managed to fix this myself as most of the information available was of no use - quite an achievement for me.

I previously had a version of the MySQL .Net Connector installed.  At some point I uninstalled it in order to get past problems with WebMatrix.  It seems that the uninstall process is a bit faulty (see here for one example: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64443)

**The fix**

1. Run the "Start the Program Install and Uninstall troubleshooter" tool on this page: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2438651
2. Tell the wizard that you're having problems uninstalling a product.
3. After a short while, select the "MySQL Net Connector " item in the list and have the wizard "repair" the uninstall

**Non WebMatrix install**
 4. If you're not installing via WebMatrix then run the installer for the connector.  Select "Custom" install and make sure that only the CORE components are installed.  The install will now complete successfully.  It seems some of the other components are what causes the install problems.  I suspect it's some sort of GAC issue, but I can't be sure.

**WebMatrix install**
 5. If you're using WebMatrix then identify which version of the MySQL connector it's trying to install (6.5.4 at the time of writing).  Get the version (and the msi package) by attempting to install whatever gallery application you are trying to install that fails (ie, WordPress).  Open up the install log.  In there should be the location of the connector msi.  Copy & paste it.
 6. Now open an elevated command prompt.  Type in

```
    msiexec /i "<pasted location of the connector msi file>"
```

Don't forget the speech marks!
Run the installer as per step 4.

Obviously, this won't be much use if you need the other components installed as well, but it's a start.

Comment: Perfect solution :-)

Comment: Big thumbs up on this.   I tried several of the solutions below.   The registry one... make sure you have a restore point, I deleted the registry item but it just wiped its name from the system and some hook still showed up under mysql which caused a series of problems.

Answer (score 11):

After 2 day long struggle and search to no avail I managed to uninstall mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.3 and install MySQL-for-visual-studio-1.2.9

I used Geek Uninstaller And Selected Force Removal which I have in my portable apps flash-drive.

1. **Download** *Geek Uninstaller* from the link below
2. **Extract** the **"Geek"** zip file
3. **run** the **geek.exe** file
4. **Look** for the **mysql-connector** or which ever program that rollsback or fails to uninstall.
5. Right Click on in and Pick **Force Removal**
6. Confirm Removal
7. It will scan for left over files and folders, then show what it has found
8. Click Finish.

   Geek Uninstaller can be downloaded here for free : [Geek Uninstaller Download Page](https://geekuninstaller.com/download)

You can also try it out yourself and see if it works I have used it for a while and I trust i can solve your problem as it also scans and removes registry entries of the program you would like to uninstall.

[image: How To force program removal with Geek Uninstaller]

Comment: Thank you!
Excellent tool that saves the hassles of digging through registry entries and removing them on software with less than stellar uninstall programs.

Answer (score 5):

I have tried all the suggestion including the Registry look-up for keys, values, etc...and delete.
But nothing has fixed, same Warning Error!

I solved this finally,

1. Go to --> RegEdit
2. Find and delete this registry key (`5FD88490-011C-4DF1-B886-F298D955171B`)

Works Perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Before you go into anything clever, go through the following steps;

1. Do you have more than one **user accounts**?

   if yes => go to all the user accounts and uninstall the MySQL Connectors starting with the lowest version.
2. Do you have any **programs open** that might be using any MySQL Connectors?

   if yes => close them before you uninstall or install the MySQL Connector
3. Have you failed on steps 1 and 2?

   if yes => start being clever, use RegEdit or any other options available. check [this link](http://zen-and-art-of-programming.blogspot.com/2013/01/removing-mysql-connector-for-net-637.html) for regedit option

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem uninstalling .NET connector 8.0.15 in Win10

The issue was with a commented out entry in my machine.config file [%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG]

This was something I had done myself...

Removing the commented out entry enabled me to uninstall/upgrade

Answer (score 1):

It could be this http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62606

It looks like quite a few people had problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (finally)

Steps:

For Windows 10 I've found for MySQL Connector Net 7.0.5 the registry key & deleted:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{5728E6B1-9316-468B-A381-8EA2867E747A}

> If you have a problem locating the registry key try running msiexec with print to log, for example:
>
> `msiexec /x "<location>\mysql-connector-net-x.x.x.msi" /L*V "<log file name>"`

I've made sure that the folder connector folder in Program Files contained the dll (MySql.Data.dll, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll, MySql.Web.dll)

Disable the rollback functionality:

- Add to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer the property "DisableRollback" with the value 1 (dword) or you can paste this to a "reg" file:

  ```
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer]
  ```

  "DisableRollback"=dword:00000001

> I suggest that you enable the rollback functionality by deleting the entry in the registry or set the value to 0.

Uninstall

Answer (score 1):

For uninstalling, this method could also be helpful if you know when you installed the program.

1. Do a system restore by going into the start menu in windows and right clicking on Computer.
2. Go into Properties and look for the System Protection. There should be a button with 
   "System Restore" on it.
3. You can choose how far back you'd like to restore your system.

This could help you uninstall the program, and many other programs. Keep in mind that this method should only be used if you have not downloaded or uninstalled anything that you permanently want to stay the same, which, in case you will have to redo it.