# Installation of MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8 failed

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I'm trying to install MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8 and Connector/NET 8.0.13 via MySQL Installer but installation of both failed. I have never had any previous version of these packages installed. I have Visual Studio Community 2017 Here is installation logs:

```
1: Download of product 'mysql-visualstudio-plugin' started from http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-for-VisualStudio/mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.8.msi
2: Download of product 'connector-net' started from http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-8.0.13.msi
1: Download of package 'MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8' succeeded
2: Download of package 'Connector/NET 8.0.13' succeeded
1: Action 16:39:24: INSTALL. 
1: 1: MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8 2: {8FAF420D-7967-44AC-B8B1-F7067944F904} 
1: Action 16:39:24: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
1: Action 16:39:24: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
1: Action 16:39:24: SetWIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED. 
1: Action 16:39:24: VS15_SetInstallationPaths. 
1: 1: MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8 2: {8FAF420D-7967-44AC-B8B1-F7067944F904} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8' failed.
2: Action 16:39:24: INSTALL. 
2: 1: MySQL Connector Net 8.0.13 2: {3BB51C01-9368-4DEF-BBD2-44914AD372AD} 
2: Action 16:39:24: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
2: Action 16:39:24: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
2: Action 16:39:25: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
2: Action 16:39:25: ValidateProductID. 
2: Action 16:39:25: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
2: Action 16:39:25: FileCost. Computing space requirements
2: Action 16:39:25: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
2: Action 16:39:25: InstallValidate. Validating install
2: Action 16:39:25: Setv45InstallUtil. 
2: Action 16:39:25: InstallInitialize. 
2: Action 16:39:25: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
2: Action 16:39:25: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
2: Action 16:39:25: GenerateScript. Generating script operations for action:
2: Updating component registration
2: Action 16:39:25: MsiUnpublishAssemblies. Unpublishing assembly information
2: Action 16:39:25: UnpublishFeatures. Unpublishing Product Features
2: Action 16:39:25: UninstallPerfCounterData. 
2: Action 16:39:25: RemoveRegistryValues. Removing system registry values
2: Action 16:39:25: RemoveShortcuts. Removing shortcuts
2: Action 16:39:25: RemoveFiles. Removing files
2: Action 16:39:25: RemoveFolders. Removing folders
2: Action 16:39:25: CreateFolders. Creating folders
2: Folder: Creating folders
2: Action 16:39:25: InstallFiles. Copying new files
2: File: Copying new files,  Directory: ,  Size: 
2: Action 16:39:25: ManagedDataInstallSetup. 
2: Action 16:39:25: ManagedDataInstall. Registering data provider in machine.config
2: Action 16:39:25: ManagedWebInstallSetup. 
2: 
2: Action 16:39:25: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
2: Shortcut: Creating shortcuts
2: Action 16:39:25: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
2: Key: Writing system registry values, Name: , Value: 
2: Action 16:39:25: InstallPerfCounterData. 
2: Action 16:39:25: RollbackRegisterPerfCounterData. 
2: 
2: Action 16:39:25: RegisterPerfCounterData. 
2: 
2: Action 16:39:25: RegisterUser. Registering user
2: Action 16:39:25: RegisterProduct. Registering product
2: Registering product
2: Action 16:39:25: MsiPublishAssemblies. Publishing assembly information
2: Application Context:Publishing assembly information, Assembly Name:
2: Action 16:39:25: PublishFeatures. Publishing Product Features
2: Feature: Publishing Product Features
2: Action 16:39:25: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
2: 
2: Action 16:39:25: InstallFinalize. 
2: Action 16:39:25: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
2: Action 16:39:25: CreateFolders. Creating folders
2: Folder: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.13\
2: Action 16:39:25: InstallFiles. Copying new files
2: File: CHANGES,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\,  Size: 12125
2: File: Google.Protobuf.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\Assemblies\v4.5.2\,  Size: 294400
2: File: Google.Protobuf.dll,  Directory: ,  Size: 294400
2: File: License,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\,  Size: 99998
2: File: MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\Assemblies\v4.5.2\,  Size: 162
2: File: MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\Assemblies\v4.5.2\,  Size: 62464
2: File: MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\Assemblies\v4.5.2\,  Size: 15529
2: File: MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\Assemblies\v4.5.2\,  Size: 24064
2: File: MySql.Data.EntityFramework.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\Assemblies\v4.5.2\,  Size: 393728
2: File: MySql.Data.EntityFramework.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\Assemblies\v4.5.2\,  Size: 21256
2: File: MySql.Data.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\Assemblies\v4.5.2\,  Size: 709632
2: File: MySql.Data.dll,  Directory: ,  Size: 709632
2: File: MySql.Data.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\Assemblies\v4.5.2\,  Size: 823007
2: File: MySql.Web.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\Assemblies\v4.5.2\,  Size: 162304
2: File: MySql.Web.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\Assemblies\v4.5.2\,  Size: 101005
2: File: MySql.Web.dll,  Directory: ,  Size: 162304
2: File: README,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\,  Size: 672
2: File: Release Notes.txt,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\,  Size: 1029
2: Action 16:39:25: ManagedDataInstall. Registering data provider in machine.config
2: Action 16:39:26: ManagedWebInstallSetup. 
2: Action 16:39:26: Rollback. Rolling back action:
2: ManagedWebInstallSetup
2: Registering data provider in machine.config
2: Copying new files
2: Creating folders
2: Updating component registration
2: 1: MySQL Connector Net 8.0.13 2: {3BB51C01-9368-4DEF-BBD2-44914AD372AD} 3: 3 
2: The action 'Install' for product 'Connector/NET 8.0.13' failed.
```

I also try to install those from MSI files downloaded from MySQL site but when i try to install i receive "MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8 Setup Wizard ended prematurely".

I try to install previous versions after that, but I only can install Connector/NET 6.9.12 but all versions of MySQL for Visual Studio ended premature.

Does anyone know how I can install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I've encountered a similar error. In my case I couldn't uninstall mysql-visualstudio-plugin-1.1.1.msi. Also had MySQL Connector Net 6.7.4 + 6.8.3 installed before (and more stuff which give and gave me many errors to solve manually).

**Before doing machine.config replacement as described below, first make a backup or rename them, of course.**

Modified versions of the machine.config seemed **the culprit**. I replaced the relevant `machine.config` file contents (configs are under `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\framework\config\{v2.0x and v4.0x folders}` and `%windir\Microsoft.NET\framework64\config{v2.0x and v4.0x folders}`) by the content of the file `machine.config.default` in the respectively same folder.

After this, complete uninstallation of older installations related to mysql became finally possible. In the past, older versions did wrong patching on the machine.configs. It took me this all day to find out uninstall was having trouble on this very strange thing. If this does not help you right away, try uninstalling before install the new mysql related files (like mysql server, mysql .net connector...).

---

### Common msi package (un)install debugging -howto-

To determine which install or uninstallation does have hidden errors, use msiexec on commandline (run it as administrator!) like this:

- When **uninstalling** an msi package use: `msiexec /x "<full-path-and-file-of>.msi" /lvx* C:\thelogfile.txt`...
- When **installing** an msi package use: `msiexec /i "<path-and-file-of>.msi" /lvx* C:\the-log-file.txt`...

...and read *the-log-file.txt* under C:\ after the msi (un)installation window is closed.

Another hint: if you are using the MySQL Installer for Windows, you can find the available msi packages at `"C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Product Cache"`.

---

### Back to installing the connector issue you and I are experiencing

While typing this, I still need to get the .net connector 8.0.16 installed. I'm reading my nice *the-log-file.txt* like mentioned before again, and see it failing on adding membership provider (probably in the machine.config again, as it did this before in earlier versions as well). I will come back later to add a possible solution on this new error.

### Updated answer / edit:

The earlier MySQL installations left some old registry keys in place… I got this idea from the answer by [@Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21263907/3700823). I followed his answer, and now installing MySQL installer for Windows v8.0.16.0 is successful, **finally**.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem with Windows 10, you should install Microsoft Ultimate Visual Studio 2012 or the following version :

1. download : https://visual-studio-2012.fr.malavida.com/#gref (or 2013, 2015 2017)
2. download : http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-for-VisualStudio/mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.8.msi
3. You can retry to install MySQL community.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have any custom settings in the VS environment export them via the Tools->Import and Export Settings option.
2. Go to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_ and delete the "privateregistry.bin" file.
3. Attempt the installation again, it should succeed.
4. Open Visual Studio.
5. If for any reason VS fails to start, again delete the "privateregistry.bin" file.
6. Import your settings if applicable. MySQL for Visual Studio should now be available.

The answer is from the following link: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,664930,664971

Comment: I've already tried this solution but unfortunately it didn't help me